# Forward parameter from tomcat url to jasper reports

Tags: tomcat, jasper-reports, oracle-apex

I use iReport 4.6.0 with Tomcat 7. I want to forward parameters from URL (Tomcat) to iReport (without using a database connection).

When I preview the report in iReport using parameter as a prompt and empty datasource (it works), but when I use the Tomcat url the parameter is not displayed (because the data source using in the url :

```
http://localhost:8087/JasperReportsIntegration/report?_repName=report2&_repFormat=pdf&_dataSource=test&_outFilename=&_repLocale=de_DE&_repEncoding=UTF-8&p_id=30
```

So, how can I forward parameter to be used in iReport?

[Preview report with iReport](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/331468preview.png)

[Preview report using Tomcat url](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/531165url.png)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved when I placed the static text and parameter in Column Header Band.
But why the 2 items aren't displayed when it placed in Detail Band??

Position of the 2 items : [enter link description here](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/472815param.png)

Review PDF using URL : [enter link description here](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/475249pdf.png)